# Parsimony-based neighborhoods in tree space

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-geometry

I have the following question about the paper [A parsimony-based metric for phylogenetic trees](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885815000135) by V. Moulton and T. Wu.

Lemma 6.2 states that only caterpillar trees have unit distance to some other tree. This seems to suggest that for any non-caterpillar tree, the 1-neighborhood should be empty. It is also shown in the paper that the parsimony-distance neighborhood contains the TBR-distance neighborhood (where TBR = [tree bisection and reconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rearrangement)). However, the TBR-neighborhood of any tree should be non-empty, since it is possible to apply a TBR move and obtain a different tree. Are there some assumptions I am missing about when the parsimony-neighborhood is empty, or when the TBR-neighborhood is contained in the parsimony neighborhood?

Also, when applying the formula in Corollary 6.6 to the non-caterpillar tree on 6 leaves, the formula seems to give the neighborhood size $|N_p| = 54$, while Lemma 6.2 suggests that the neighborhood is empty. Should applying this formula really give $|N_p| = 0$, which I am misreading somehow?